# Python: Importing modules into CGI script

Tags: python, apache, centos, cgi

I'm hoping someone might be able to explain to me why this is happening?

I am running httpd on Centos 7 with Python 2.7

I have a python module in `/home/user/Path/to/module.py`. Lets say, for example, it prints "Hello World!"

```
print("Hello World!")
```

I then try to import it into the file `/var/www/cgi-bin/index.py` like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user/Path/to/')

print('Content-type: text/html\n\n')
print('<!DOCTYPE html>')
print('<html lang="en">')
print('<head>')
print('</head>')
print('<body>')
print('<h1>')
import module
print('</h1>')
print('</body>')
print('</html>')
```

If I were to run this from the terminal I get the following:

```
Content-type: text/html


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>
Hello World!
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I curl this URL `curl http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/index.py` I get the following message:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at
root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred,
and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
</body></html>
```

Httpd error logs show this error?

```
[Sat Aug 19 10:38:16.107635 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 4061] [client 127.0.0.1:39608] AH01215: Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Aug 19 10:38:16.107684 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 4061] [client 127.0.0.1:39608] AH01215:   File "/var/www/cgi-bin/index.py", line 7, in <module>
[Sat Aug 19 10:38:16.107691 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 4061] [client 127.0.0.1:39608] AH01215:     import module
[Sat Aug 19 10:38:16.107702 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 4061] [client 127.0.0.1:39608] AH01215: ImportError: No module named module
[Sat Aug 19 10:38:16.109117 2017] [cgi:error] [pid 4061] [client 127.0.0.1:39608] End of script output before headers: index.py
```

Contents of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` :

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Update:

Attempted to get around this by removing this line:

```
sys.path.append('/home/user/Path/to/')
```

And instead creating a symlink to the module in `/var/www/cgi-bin/` which appears to work but my module accesses the folder `/home/user/Path/to/folder` which is throwing an access denied error in httpd logs.

Update:

Got this working using Django instead. It is, however, still a mystery to me why this wont work using Apache?